# Regular expression for database naming

Tags: php, sql, regex

I've thousand of queries I need to execute from a text file.

See bellow a kind of query I have:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM T1 A 
    INNER JOIN DB2.dbo.CI_T1 B ON A.id= B.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T3 C ON B.id = C.id
    WHERE ...
```

Some of tables are well named (`database.owner.table_name`), and some other no (`table_name`).

How can I use a regex to update each query to replace unqualified instances of `table_name` with `database.owner.table_name`?

I write fiddle to test it: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/9SH and http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/9SF

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What language are you working with to do the replacement? Do the tables all have aliases? If not, doing this replacement in the `ON` clauses would be very difficult.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I'm working with PHP

Comment: @RC. I just highlight it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I use following regex with `preg_replace` function:

```
$regex = '#(FROM)\s+((?!\.)[[:alnum:]_]+)\s+(\w*)\s*(INNER|LEFT|WHERE|\))#i';
$regex2 = '#(JOIN)\s+((?!\.)[[:alnum:]_]+)\s+(\w*)\s*(ON)#i';
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I wouldn't attempt to use a regex. While it is trivial for a simple SELECT like you provided (although you seem to be having some difficulties) it won't be long before you find [how difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) it is to parse a programming language using a simple regex.

I'd start with an [SQL parser](https://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/).